# uri_to_assoc(n) doesn't work after routing

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

So this currently loads the page for me.

/controllername/view/id/27/title/shoes

However, I want the user to be able to type in:

/controllername/27/shoes

to view the file. So in the routing file, I made a rule like this,

$route['controllername/(:num)/(:any)'] = "controllername/view/id/$1/title/$2";

The original address works with uri_to_assoc(n) because I have it as

```
    $array = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(3);
    $id = $array['id'];
    $title = $array['title'];
```

But once I route it and use the new address to access the file, I get the errors:
Message: Undefined index: id
Message: Undefined index: title

I do not get these errors with my original url way of accessing it. I guess the value of uri_to_assoc(3) changes once the url is changed but I thought the routing function would take care of that. Can anyone help me get rid of these variable errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you'll want `ruri_to_assoc`:

> http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html
>
> `$this->uri->ruri_to_assoc(n)`
>
> This function is identical to [uri_to_assoc], except that it creates
> an associative array using the re-routed URI in the event you are
> using CodeIgniter's URI Routing feature.

You should still validate your array indices anyways, in case the URL itself is invalid.

Comment: Thanks Wesley, this totally did the trick for me! Can you tell me what an associative array is and how does it relate to to routing? I'm just trying to learning the CI system.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you're asking me. The `r*` functions of the URI class work with the `r`outed segments, the ones in your `routes.php` array values. The associative array is formed from taking each segment of the URL and basically going: First segment -> first key, second segment -> first value, third segment -> second key, fourth segment -> second value.

Comment: An associative array just basically means one in explicit key => value format, where the keys are (typically) strings. All array values have keys, but they might be *implied* numeric keys. Try `print_r($your_array)` to check out what's in it.